# how convert object to float in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
base = base["DY"].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float) 

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '6.1%'
```

How convert string to float in pandas in only column?

Comment: Your string seems to contain a '%' sign. Please show some sample input.

Comment: You want `6.1%` to be converted into `0.061` or rather `6.1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```py
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({"col": ["4,2", "5.79", "-6,23%", "9.6%"]})

df["col2"]=df["col"].str.replace(",",".").str.replace("%", "*0.01").map(eval)

>>> df

      col    col2
0     4,2  4.2000
1    5.79  5.7900
2  -6,23% -0.0623
3    9.6%  0.0960
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this below:-

```
base = base["DY"].str.replace(',' , '.').replace('%', '').astype(float)
```

Comment: I do this: 

base['DY'] = base['DY'].str.rstrip('%').str.replace(',', ".").astype('float') / 100.0

result

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '46.489.4'

Comment: is the value  46,489.6 ?